# Wordpress : I changed the name and location of my main folder and now I can't access it in browser?

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed Wordpress in a  folder called "wordpress" in root, but I changed that to "blog" and put it into another folder named "get_a_class." Now I get a page with no CSS.

Comment: Please try not to write your questions the same way you would IM your 6 year old cousin. Your question would've been answered quickly by searching the WordPress site, and if not, asking on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. This is not a programming question, it doesn't belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: if u know the answer, put it on the line else don waste ur time on passing remarks like that.

Answer (score 4):

Go here step by step

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: tnx dude ... only few ppl hv pation for helping others

Answer (score 0):

i found the very easy solution for that and that was to go in database and make changes in the table wp-option and change site url attribute and home attribute and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Database editing easier when ever you have folder changed or domain change happens. For step by step instruction for migrating from one domain to another domain follow www.sayopenweb.com/migrating-wordpress-from-one-domain-to-another-domain/